# Install apt packages using gnome software

Tags: apt, gnome, software-center, gnome-software, 23.10

I've installed the gnome-software package using apt (in Ubuntu 23.10, where gnome-software isn't the default software manager) and I've also installed gnome-software-plugin-flatpak that allows me to install flatpak packages using the gnome-software. Now I want to install apt packages using gnome-software, how can I do that? (snap and deb were there by default in gnome-software)

Comment: apt is not a package format, but a command line tool for installing deb packages. Sadly, Gnome-Software does not show deb app packages without appdata.xml/metainfo.xml files .

Comment: @MerilynNe But DEB packages are showing up on the gnome-software (by default). It was there by default when I did `sudo apt install gnome-software`